# Finding the firewall port that filters internet traffic

Tags: firewalls, ports

In my office, we have static IP's for each system. All the internet traffic from our systems are filtered with a Fortiguard firewall. Is it the default gateway where the firewall is installed? How can I find the open ports that are allowed to connect to the internet?  I to ping websites but it always returns "request timed out". I guess the firewall has something to do with it.

I have admin rights on my system and nmap and Wireshark installed.

My static IP     - 10.6.154.202

Default Gateway  - 10.6.144.1

Subnet Mask      - 255.255.240.0

Comment: " I have admin rights in my system" but if you dont have admin-rights in your network you shouldnt think a bout or try such stuff.

Comment: If you are using MS product then http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308127 may help you a bit

Comment: @that guy from over there - "if you dont have admin-rights in your network". I don't understand this. Does this mean unless i am the network admin, i shouldn't try knowing it.?

Comment: "Is it the default gateway where the firewall is installed.?" Can someone clarify this and also the ping- "request timed out" issue

Comment: A FW security policy for internet surfing should only have needed internet services for the users(http,https,email,ftp), all other traffics are dropped, thats why you get ping request timed out

Comment: @user45569: do you have a company-(security|user)-policy? why dont you just ask your network-admins? there might be various methods implemented like transparent proxies, white/blacklisting etc pp. in our company, if someone from the inside is portscanning around he/she gets some visit from an angry operations-dude. if you want to know something: ask your staff, if you want to be mister superclever, be prepared to get a bloody nose, thats what i wanted to say.

Comment: @that guy from over there: Thanks for the heads up. I spoke with my admin. He told inorder to restrict certain websites, firewall filters our traffic. Do you know what the question i asked- Why ping doesn't work. I asked him once again to be sure but he didn't seem interested in answering me. Oh i did execute a basic port scanning command in nmap for hours. I wasn't visited by some angry ops guy

Comment: @hoa: Oh i see. Yes i researched a bit and came to know ping uses ICMP protocol which might be blocked. So you mean only ports for http, https, email, ftp alone would be opened.?

Comment: As per the OP's comments to my answer, not only is the real issue not about firewalls and ports, but it is about circumventing his school's security. Voting to close.

Comment: @user45569 If the firewall is correctly configured, ICMP outbound will be blocked, and I'd expect these days that only 80/TCP and 443/TCP (HTTP and HTTP(S)) will be allowed.  As to accessing websites restricted by your network admin, I'd recommend getting a personal 3G capable device and browse from that :)

Answer (score 3):

By using the ping command, you are using a protocol and port that is non-standard for Web traffic. Pings are commonly blocked at firewalls.

If you can browse to websites, then you have port 80 (http) open and likely port 443 (https).

What you need is a program that can do the same thing as 'ping' but not using ICMP and using specific ports that you want to test. Nmap can do that as can many other tools. The process you want to do is called 'firewalking' (walking the firewall ports to see what is allowed).

But I have to say that it sounds like you need a little more knowledge on the basics of networking before firewalking will make sense. It also sounds like you have no good reason to know what ports are allowed and that you are trying to bypass the security of your company's network.

Maybe if you explained why you need to know the ports that are open, we can be more specific...

Comment: @schroeder- I know the basics of networking but not an expert. What i didn't know was ping command also gets blocked by a firewall according to the rules set. I was curious about using nmap. "Firewalking"- Glad that i am learning something. I work at a lab [academic university] and bypassing the security can be done using certain VPNs. I am trying to figure out how our firewall setup works so that i can find if there is a way to disguise or a loophole that would allow me to use the same setup and browse restricted websites. Note: proxies, Tor, SSH Tunneling using putty, OpenVPN don't work

Comment: Did i answer your question. Can you help me

Comment: So, your question is really about restricted websites? That has nothing to do with firewalls or ports. That is a DNS issue. This is also a question about circumventing the security of a system, which is not allowed here. Voting to close.

Comment: @schroeder - while the move to close is still valid, it is worth highlighting that circumventing the security of a system is only off topic if they don't have a basic understanding of how to do so.  If they understand the concepts involved and are looking for clarification on some aspect of it, it is on topic.  (For example for penetration testing.)  This situation is still off topic though.